Unknown '70s British children's TV series with Aztec culture, time travel and human sacrifice
Back in the 1970s a television series on British television.
I'm placing this around 1976 plus or minus a couple of years.
The title sequence began with the image of a wooden bowl (primitive drum?) as seen from the side, sitting on a wooden sideboard in a house. It has markings of figures and glyphs consistent with what might be perhaps Aztec culture and designs.
The Music (drumming and rhythmic, on ancient musical instruments) picks up pace, the bowl mysteriously spins and begins to glow. The music, spinning and glowing climax and the show begins.
Two children living in a house where the bowl also turns up, perhaps collected by a parent or as a gift to them. The children are intrigued by the bowl and speculate about it. They soon discover it can be triggered to transport them back in time to south America at the height of a culture there.
Impressive architecture, a great step-pyramid with an entrance to where the Leader/King and Priests live.  At a few steps below the stairs to the entrance to the pyramid, there is a sacrificial altar. The common folk can gather in the large paved space below. Various ornamental or religious statues adorn the place. Surrounding all that is their living space and a few farms, surrounding that is a jungle.
There is a main antagonist. A middle-aged high-priest type (played by a very familiar face) , tanned and decadent but not fat. He is superficially charming and manipulative. He's the one called upon to persuade the "King" of correct decisions by his religious authority - and he is the one who makes human sacrifices.
The climax of the series involves tension between the children's scientific understanding and the religious view locally. There is a solar eclipse prophesied to bring great harm to the kingdom. As the time approaches a sacrificial victim is chosen, someone in whom the children are emotionally invested, perhaps a friend. The Sacrifice is delayed at the last minute and the priest ends up dead. The eclipse passes and the season ends with the children going home.
-I've also a stray memory, perhaps unrelated that the priest had at some point managed to travel to the future and learn to understand eclipses as the modern world does - but on returning to his time still elected to use his power to make the human sacrifice.

The solar eclipse is a plot point in Tintin, Prisoners of the Sun, where Tintin and his companions (Captain Haddock and Prof Calculus) are to be put to death, with their choice as to time of death, so Tintin chooses it to time with an eclipse. I don't think it was one of the Tintin series made into films though

That sounds similar in many respects to The Feathered Serpent (1976 for the first series and 1978 for the second); however, it doesn't have the time travel plot, as far as I can tell.
The series is a British children's show from 1976, set in Aztec Mexico, featuring much intrigue, human sacrifice, etc. The antagonistic high-priest type is played by a former Doctor Who, Patrick Troughton; and a solar eclipse is a key part of the ending of the first series, at the timestamp here:



(With the priest ending up dead).

That's interesting, quite correct of course, but I seem to have conflated two different shows. I wonder what show the bowl/drum, time travel/transport to different lands one was from. I'll wait the customary 48 hours and maybe someone in the meantime will fill us in.
